# Update Mongo from Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to Node.

From the Mongo shell I issue this command on the collection "system.user"

```
db.system.users.find({_id: "test.admin"})
```

And get back this record

```
{
  "_id": "test.admin",
  "user": "admin",
  "db": "test",
  "credentials": {
    "SCRAM-SHA-1": {
      "iterationCount": 10000,
      "salt": "hBehS02+DJL+XX92dpuXnw==",
      "storedKey": "6TifIE7lc4TLKkMSYC6yjX/WZ5Y=",
      "serverKey": "gqxsc9a6Z8HvBLpZl8bNxiPsYWA="
    }
  },
  "roles": [{
    "role": "root",
    "db": "admin"
  }]
}
```

My question is has anyone got an example JavaScript that will show me how to update the roles attribute. So that after the JavaScript/node update

```
db.system.users.find({_id: "test.admin"})
```

will then read

```
{
  "_id": "test.admin",
  "user": "admin",
  "db": "test",
  "credentials": {
    "SCRAM-SHA-1": {
      "iterationCount": 10000,
      "salt": "hBehS02+DJL+XX92dpuXnw==",
      "storedKey": "6TifIE7lc4TLKkMSYC6yjX/WZ5Y=",
      "serverKey": "gqxsc9a6Z8HvBLpZl8bNxiPsYWA="
    }
  },
  "roles": [{
    "role": "dbowner",
    "db": "admin"
  }]
}
```

Changes the "role" : "root" to "role" : "dbowner"

I'm looking for the most "atomic" way to do it, perhaps some sort of json parse.
Not just a simple string replace.

Comment: Did you search to mongodb to node or mongoose?

Comment: You should probably read this entire section before proceeding further:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/

Comment: Thanks for the hint to use Mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this

```
db.system.users.updateOne({_id: "test.admin"}, {"roles.role":"dbowner"}, {upsert:1});
```